# Estimate minimum number of repititions in Bernoulli trial

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

> Let be $X_i$ a Bernoulli distributed random variable, such that $P(X_i=1)=\frac{2}{27}$ and $P(X_i=0)=\frac{25}{27}$. Then, $X:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$ obeys a binomial distribution, where $\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{2n}{27}$ and $\mathbb{V}(X)=\frac{50n}{27^2}$.
>
> Use Chebycheff inequality $P(|X-\mathbb{X}(X)|\geq \epsilon)\leq\frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}$ to estimate the smallest $n$ such that the probability of at least one success is $\geq 0.25$.
>
> (**Do use Chebycheff inequality** to find an estimate and don't calculate the true $n$.)

---

**First approach:**

We are trying to show that $P(X\geq 1)\geq 0.25$ which is equivalent to $P(X<1)<0.75$. We see that
\begin{align*}
&P(X< 1)=P(X-\mathbb{E}(X)<1-\mathbb{E}(X))=P(\mathbb{E}(X)-X>\mathbb{E}(X)-1)\leq P(|\mathbb{E}(X)-X|>\mathbb{E}(X)-1).
\end{align*}
If we assume $\mathbb{E}(X)-1=\frac{2n}{27}-1>0$, then Chebycheff inequality (CI) yields
\begin{align*}
&P(X< 1)\leq P(|\mathbb{E}(X)-X|>\mathbb{E}(X)-1)\overset{\text{CI}}{\leq}\frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{(\mathbb{E}(X)-1)^2}\leq 0.75\\
&\implies \frac{\frac{50n}{27^2}}{(\frac{2n}{27}-1)^2}\leq 0.75\implies n\geq 39.
\end{align*}

---

**Second approach:**

We start with
\begin{align*}
P(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|\geq \epsilon)\leq\frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}\iff P(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|\leq \epsilon)\geq1-\frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}
\end{align*}
and because of $\{|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|\leq \epsilon\}\subseteq \{\mathbb{E}(X)-X\leq \epsilon\}=\{X\geq \mathbb{E}(X)- \epsilon\}$, it follows

\begin{align*}
P(X\geq \mathbb{E}(X)-\epsilon)\geq1-\frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}.
\end{align*}
If we assume $\mathbb{E}(X)-\epsilon>0$ and look at $1-\frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}\geq 0.25$, then tinkering around with $n$ and $\epsilon>0$ simultanously delivers $n=18$ (and $\epsilon\approx1.31$).

---

Why do the two approaches produce different results? As the first approach yields a much larger $n$ there must be an issue.

Comment: I think you have a typo: $P(X_i=\color{red}1)=\frac{2}{27}$ and $P(X_i=\color{red}1)=\frac{25}{27}$. One of the red numbers should be $0$.